# LIKE solution for SQL MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm having trouble with my LIKE in this SQL. I'm not really sure if this is even fixable. I've looked for every possible way to get the LIKE to work the way I would like it to work, but can't seem to find a solution. My issues is that field [program] is not written exactly the same in table CFRRR (which is where a and b get their values) as it is written in table attendance. For example: In table CFRRR program could be CW/CF or MC/CF or just CW and so on. But in table attendance Programs could be written CW/MC/CF. Because of this the code not selecting a record.

Is it possible that the code can read that both have CW or both have CF in the values?

```
a = Program
b = language


Set db = CurrentDb

strSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 userID 
          FROM attendance 
          where attendance.Programs LIKE '%" & a & "'
            AND attendance.Language LIKE '*" & b & "*'
            AND attendance.Status = 'Available'
            AND attendance.Tracking = 0"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
```

Comment: Why use LIKE? Just create a work table with all the possible values (looks like 2^3 + 2^2 + 2 = 13 to me) and do a simple INNER JOIN to it.  Remember that LIKE is *not* a regular expression parser even in full-bodies SQL dialects.

Answer (score 0):

You need a "contain" function because with `LIKE` you can't do what you want. You have to divide the search terms first and you can use the "/" symbol to split them. for example the key "CW/CF" need to be splited (see vba `split` function) in search terms "CW" and "CF" (and same for languajes). And then find through `SQl` each search term with `LIKE "*searchTerm*"`. You may need to build on the fly an SQL string (using `for...next` and looping the Array generated with the split function).
result of the function would be this (in this case "a" has two terms and "b" also two terms, so arrays goes from 0 to 1):

```
"SELECT TOP 1 userID 
      FROM attendance 
      where Programs LIKE '*" & termP(0) & "*' AND " & _
           "Programs LIKE '*" & termP(1) & "*' AND " & _
           "languaje LIKE '*" & termL(0) & "*' AND " & _
           "languaje LIKE '*" & termL(1) & "*' " & _
        AND attendance.Status = 'Available'
        AND attendance.Tracking = 0"
```

you can put the real values in the `SQl` string instead of the array positions.

Or you can think a better structure for your tables.